# jQuery form submit not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have 2 forms in one html file(Not nested). Each do their own thing and do not rely on each other. The problem i'm currently facing is that `$(form).submit((event)=>{code})` only works on:

```
<form id="mainForm" action='' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!--Cover image-->
    <ul class="error" id="coverImageLink_errors"></ul>
    <div class="cover-img">
        {{ mainForm.coverImageLink|add_class:'actual-img' }}
        <img src="#" id="cover" alt="Your image" style="color: black;">
    </div>

    <!--Music data part-->
    <div class="music-data">
        <ul class="error" id="albumName_errors"></ul>
        <label for="{ mainForm.albumName.id_for_label }">title</label><br>
        {{ mainForm.albumName }} <br><br>
    </div>
    <input id='albumSubmit' type="submit" value="Next" class="main-form-upload">
</form>

<script>
    $('#mainForm').submit((event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('AJAX CALLED FOR MAIN FORM');
    });
</script>
```

But not on:

```
<form id="AdvancedForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="last-step-error" id="advancedForm.non_field_errors"></ul>
    
    <section id="main-section">
     
        <!-- compresso page -->
        <div id="compresso-page">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="name">0. Hello world</div>
                <ul class="pre-errors">
                    <li>Video file is not supported</li>
                    <li>+2 more</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </section>

    <div style="height: 20px;"></div> <!-- prevents collision with button -->
    <input type="submit" value="Release" onclick="alert('Advanced form submit pressed')">
</form>

<script>
    $('#AdvancedForm').submit((event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('AJAX CALLED FOR ADVANCED FORM')
        const url = '{% url "validate-upload-collection" %}'
    })
</script>
```

I see `AJAX CALLED FOR MAIN FORM` but not `AJAX CALLED FOR ADVANCED FORM`.
The advanced form is `display='none'` by default

`console.log(document.getElementById('AdvancedForm'))` returns [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2u657ksa/1/)

If you are confused with `{{ something }}`, it's just some django(Web framework) variable syntax. Those variables will be filled in on the server side so that is not present in the html.

Comment: If you do `$("#AdvancedForm")[0]` in the console, do you see that it's correctly grabbing your form?

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `$(document).on("submit", "#AdvancedForm", function() { alert("try this"); });`

Comment: @g23 I did just that and an object of length 1 is returned. My form is inside

Comment: @freedomn-m Nope.

Comment: What about `console.log($("[id=Advancedform]").length)`?

Comment: @freedomn-m Ok...now it returns 0, what does this mean?

Comment: What if you try adding the `$("#AdvancedForm").on("submit", (evt) => { evt.preventDefault(); console.log("it works?"); })` in the console and then clicking the submit button?

Comment: @g23 Does not work. It's almost as if the event handler doesn't exist

Comment: It means your advanced form doesn't exist with that ID when you run that `.length` code.

Comment: @freedomn-m Wait a minute the 'f'  in "Advancedform" is supposed to be capitalized, that's why it returned 0. When i did capitalize the 'f' it returned 1, so my form does indeed exist

Comment: That's very weird... You could try `$("#AdvancedForm")[0].onsubmit = (evt) => { e.preventDefault(); console.log("this works???"); };` the `[0]` grabs the actual element from jQuery and then adding an `.onsubmit` to it should hopefully work

Comment: Ok, my bad with the typo

Comment: @g23 Very wierd. Anyway i tried `$("#AdvancedForm")[0].onsubmit = (evt) => { }` , but no luck

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `onclick="alert('Advanced form submit pressed')"` interferes with your handler. Try to remove that from the submit button.

One other thing I see is that the second form has no real fields? That might be another thing. Try adding `<input type="text" name="test" />`

Comment: Tried that but no luck